# How to disable the HEAD request in java?

Tags: java, retrofit2, okhttp, head

I have a POST request in Retrofit2 and unfortunately have 403 response.
I asked the Server-Side guys to see their logs, they told me that I'm not sending a POST request instead I sent a HEAD request and therefore IIS dons't respond to my actual request(They don't accept HEAD requests).
I need to Know what can i do to disable this "Pre Request" to server.
Down below is my retrofit Log:

```
Network: --> POST https://uat.onepay.com.my:65002/TADWeb2/pos/
Network: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Network: Content-Length: 152
Network: Accept: application/json
Network: User-Agent: POS
Network: {"d":"knJTBOx9aldlnWJYiw1LxSVBD47sga+F8a1hUCg3kNs=","t":"2019-04-08 13:46:44","h":"h7kLsZ0X1mCZtdN1zYcGvByxQO2hcfHGd1+ua8QDhFk=","m":"fc:ee:e6:5:60:be"}
Network: --> END POST (152-byte body)
Network: <-- 403 Forbidden https://uat.onepay.com.my:65002/TADWeb2/pos/ (269ms)
Network: Content-Type: text/html
Network: Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Network: X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Network: Date: Mon, 08 Apr 2019 05:46:42 GMT
Network: Content-Length: 1233
Network: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

**Note: this api works on Postman**

Comment: Are the "server guys" 100% sure? It seems weird to me that a HEAD request is done before a POST request. An OPTIONS request is quite common for CORS purposes, but a HEAD request seems weird to me (I might be wrong though)

Comment: According to your log, the HTTP request method is `POST` not `HEAD`, so it seems that is not the issue.

Comment: @jspcal How can It be HEAD when my Log says It is a post request

Comment: Could there be a proxy/cache/router in between that's modifying the request in some way? Or perhaps the `HEAD` is generated by a different component?

Comment: @jspcal note that this api does work on postman

Comment: I don't see HEAD in log above.

Comment: @ Antoniossss the Log is client side Log not IIS Log